# Creating a sales list that allows users to enter multiple items

Tags: python

I've been working on a project for my class in python and I feel like no matter what I do I can't get it right. We're supposed to create a program that captures 3 items and then 4 bits of information for each item. AKA: Item: x, Quantity: x, price $x, weight x pounds. Then it should print out a subtotal, shipping & handling cost, tax total, and final total. The issue I'm having is that we're not allowed to create a variable for each item and must do everything in a loop. No matter what I've tried all I can do is get everything to print out the last data entered.

Here's my code so far:

```
def main():

    #Range of 3 so that user may enter 3 seperate items
    for i in range(3):

        #Grabs user input for item description and/or name
        strDescription = str(input("Enter description of item: "))

        #Grabs user input for price of item
        fltPrice = float(input("Enter price of item: $ "))

        #Grabs user input for quanitity of item
        intQuantity = int(input("Enter quantity of item: "))

        #Grabs user input for weight of item in pounds
        fltWeight = float(input("Enter weight of item in pounds: "))

        #Subtotal is equal to price times number of items purchased
        fltPriceSub = fltPrice*intQuantity

        #Shipping 25 cents per pound
        intShipping = (.25*fltWeight)

        #There is a base fee of $5 per order applied to shipping
        intBaseRate = 5

        #Tax is 9 cents per dollar
        fltTax = 0.09*fltPriceSub

        fltPriceSubTotal = fltPriceSub+fltPriceSub+fltPriceSub

        intShippingTotal = intShipping+intShipping+intShipping+intBaseRate

        fltTaxTotal = fltTax+fltTax+fltTax



        #Order total is the subtotal+shipping+tax added together
        fltOrderTotal = fltPriceSubTotal+intShippingTotal+fltTaxTotal


    print("You have purchased ", strDescription, "")
    print("Your subtotal is ", fltPriceSubTotal, "")
    print("Shipping and handling is ", intShippingTotal, "")
    print("The tax is ", fltTaxTotal, "")
    print("The order total is ",fltOrderTotal, "")



main()
```

If anyone could steer me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

Comment: You can use a dict to save all your inputs. It that is allowed to use.